# How to bind a row from one column to another in SQL Server based on no criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a #temp table that gets me the data in the following structure

```
Number  |MobileNumber|FirstName|LastName|Voucher|MessageContent|MessageStatus
--------+------------+---------+--------+-------+--------------+-------------
340046  |1158963214  |trisha   |govender|NULL   |Hello         |    0
354252  |1124589630  |Peter    |Ngcobo  |NULL   |Hello         |    0
385603  |2587465974  |Chris    |Pat     |NULL   |Hello         |    0
385674  |1256559878  |chris    |pat     |NULL   |Hello         |    0
385679  |4485484656  |john     |doe     |NULL   |hello         |    0
```

from the following query

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#results') IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #results
END

SELECT DISTINCT
    t.Number,
    FA.MobileNumber, FA.FirstName, FA.LastName,
    CAST(null AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS Voucher,
    MessageContent,
    CAST(0 AS BIT) AS MessageStatus
INTO  
    #results
FROM // has multiple join statements in here
```

I have an other permanent table structured in the database as follows

```
Voucher  |  Flag
---------+-------
ush54df  |  0
th545th4 |  0
cb215gt  |  0
dg84gd35g|  0
dfg15rg1 |  0
```

I am trying to assign a single voucher for each row in the `#temp` results table, however I don't have any criteria from the `#results` table to join onto the permanent voucher table.

I am trying to achieve that when I run the query for the #results table it should add a voucher into the voucher column as follows:

```
Number |MobileNumber |FirstName |LastName|Voucher |MessageContent|MessageStatus
-------+-------------+----------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------
340046 |1158963214   |trisha    |govender|th545th4| Hello        |0
354252 |1124589630   |Peter     |Ngcobo  |g54er8g4| Hello        |0
385603 |2587465974   |Chris     |Pat     |ush54df | Hello        |0
385674 |1256559878   |chris     |pat     |dfg15rg1| Hello        |0
385679 |4485484656   |john      |doe     |cb215gt | Hello        |0
```

Once I know how to achieve the above then I can then be able to set the voucher flag to a value of 1 so that I wont use the same voucher twice.for example:

```
Voucher  |  Flag
---------+-------
ush54df  |  1
th545th4 |  1
cb215gt  |  1
dg84gd35g|  0
dfg15rg1 |  1
dg5r4g   |  0
we8r78e4 |  0
g54er8g4    1
```

So my question is how do I assign a voucher number to a Number from the #temp results table? I tried to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 2))` but the `#temp` table doesn't match the voucher table numbers, your guidance will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select r.*, v.voucher
from (select r.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from #results r
     ) r left join
     (select v.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from vouchers v
     ) v
     on r.seqnum = v.seqnum;
```

For every row in `#results`, this will assign one `voucher`, if it exists.  If the number of rows in `#results` is more than the number of vouchers, then the excess will have `NULL`.

You can actually do the assignment using `update`:

```
update r
    set voucher = v.voucher
from (select r.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from #results r
     ) r join
     (select v.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from vouchers v
     ) v
     on r.seqnum = v.seqnum;
```

Comment: Hi,in place of new() what would i assign? it tells me 'new' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @KatePillay . . . That was a typo.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon,this helped alot, i just have one question just say after i assign the voucher and i set its flag to 1 that means that this voucher is already been used.Now if i run the query again at a later time and i get back the same Numbers from the results table with a few extra row,does that mean that the same Number will be assigned a new voucher all the time?,i only want one number fixed to one voucher always

Comment: @KatePillay . . . In the subquery for the voucher, add `where flag = 0`, so you get only unused vouchers.